# How exactly is this tensor symmetric?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices

I am trying to solve P&S Problem 3.3:

> [...]
> Let $k^\mu_0, k^\mu_1$ be fixed 4-vectors satisfying $k^2_0 = 0, k^2_1
> > = -1, k_0 \cdot k_1 = 0$. Define basic spinors in the following way: Let $u_{L0}$ be the left-handed spinor for a fermion with momentum
> $k_0$. Let $u_{R0} = \frac{1}{2} u_{L0}$
> [...]
> Show that $\not k_0 u_{R0} = 0$
> [...]

The solution to this is simple enough:

$$\not k_0 u_{R0} = \not k_0 \not k_1 u_{L0} = \gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu k_{0\mu} k_{1\nu}u_{L0} = (2g^{\mu\nu}-\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu)k_{0\mu}k_{1\nu} = -\not k_1\not k_0,$$

since $k_0\cdot k_1$ by definition. Now, using the commutator $[\not k_0, \not k_1] = 4i\sigma^{\mu\nu}k_{0\mu}k_{1\nu}$:

$$\not k_0\not k_1 u_{L0} = 2i\sigma^{\mu\nu}k_{0\mu}k_{1\nu}u_{L0}$$

According to a sample solution [here](https://theoreticalmaximum.files.wordpress.com/2017/07/intro-to-qft-solutions2.pdf), the term of the form $\sigma^{\mu\nu}k_{0\mu}k_{1\nu}$ vanishes, since $\sigma$ is antisymmetric and $k_{0\mu}k_{1\nu}$ is symmetric. I considered this possibility but decided that $k_{00}k_{11}$ is generally not the same as $k_{01}k_{10}$. So, how exactly is the outer product of two fixed four-vectors symmetric?

EDIT: I have seen [similar answers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/639226/understanding-a-solution-to-qft) on the web that explain this for the case that $k_0 = k_1$. In that case it's acceptable. But that is clearly not the case here.